# C# TCP Read welcome message and send Command

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm having some trouble with a simple TCP Read/Write application where I need to write a command to a device/host. Normally I can do this using a stream.Write() command however with this particular device, it seems to send an initial welcome message back (PJLINK 0) before any command can be sent to it. I can send the commands fine using PuTTY but when using C# I think my connection is closing before I can get my command through.

So my question would be how can I adjust my code below to receive that welcome message and then send my command back (I don't need to read a response) without the TcpClient closing the connection early?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
                using (tcpClientA = new TcpClient())
                {
                    int portA = 4352;

                    if (!tcpClientA.BeginConnect("10.0.2.201", portA, null, null).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Failed to connect.");
                    }

                    while (tcpClientA.Connected)
                    {
                        using (streamA = tcpClientA.GetStream())
                        {
                            if (type == "raw")
                            {

                                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                                byte[] writeBufferC = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("%1 INPT 32$0D"); //Command I need to send
                                byte[] readBufferC = new byte[tcpClientA.ReceiveBufferSize];
                                string fullServerReply = null;
                                using (var writer = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    do
                                    {
                                        int numberOfBytesRead = streamA.Read(readBufferC, 0, readBufferC.Length);
                                        if (numberOfBytesRead <= 0)
                                        {
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        writer.Write(writeBufferC, 0, writeBufferC.Length);
                                    } while (streamA.DataAvailable);
                                    fullServerReply = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(writer.ToArray());
                                    Console.WriteLine(fullServerReply.Trim());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**Update 1**
Removed the BeginConnect and Async methods.

```
                using (tcpClientA = new TcpClient())
                {
                    int portA = 4352;

                    tcpClientA.Connect("10.0.2.201", portA);

                    while (tcpClientA.Connected)
                    {
                        using (streamA = tcpClientA.GetStream())
                        {
                            if (type == "raw")
                            {
                                byte[] readBufferC = new byte[tcpClientA.ReceiveBufferSize];
                                byte[] writeBufferC = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("%1 INPT 31$0D"); //Command I need to send

                                string fullServerReply = null;
                                using (var writer = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    do
                                    {
                                        streamA.Read(readBufferC, 0, readBufferC.Length); //First read
                                        writer.Write(writeBufferC, 0, writeBufferC.Length); //Send command
                                    } while (streamA.DataAvailable);
                                    fullServerReply = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readBufferC.ToArray());
                                    Console.WriteLine(fullServerReply.Trim());
                                    tcpClientA.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean by "message"? If you don't know, you will have no chance of getting this right. To send and receive messages, you must know *precisely* what a message *is*, otherwise, there's no way to write code to do it properly. TCP is not a message protocol, it's a byte stream protocol. To send messages, you need a message protocol -- and we have no idea what message protocol you are using because you didn't tell us.

Comment: Is it in some async method? I suspect the `BeginConnect` is the problem. Skip the `AsyncWaitHandle` part, and connect synchronously. Use `.Connect`

Comment: Also You do read after each command. Is it working that way? By the spec it looks like You need to read once at the beginning. You also write the %1... string to the memory stream after each buffer read.

Comment: The command is in my code: "%1 INPT 32$0D"

I have removed the BeginConnect and AsyncWaitHandle as you suggested, just using .Connect now, however it doesn't seem to be doing anything different.

If I try reading at the beginning, it still seems to close the connection before writing the command, and if I try to read after sending the command the application freezes up it seems. Updated main post with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataAvailable` does not tell you how much data will be sent in the future by the remote side. It's use is almost always a bug. Here, it causes you to randomly exit the loop early.

Read, until you have all the bytes you expect or until the stream is being closed.

Is this a line-based protocol? Instantiate a `StreamReader` and draw entire lines from the stream.

`while (tcpClientA.Connected)` accomplishes nothing. Even if it returns true, the connection could be lost 1 nanosecond later. Your code has to deal with that anyway. It should be `while (true)`. This is not a bug, it just shows weak TCP understanding so I point it out.

Remove all usages of `ReceiveBufferSize`. This value means nothing of significance. Instead, use a fixed buffer size. I find that 4096 works well with not very high throughput connections.

`numberOfBytesRead <= 0` should be `==0`. Again, not a bug but you don't seem to understand exactly what the API does. This is dangerous.

In the updated code you're not using the return value of `streamA.Read` which is a bug. You have tried to fix that bug by trimming off the resulting `\0` chars. That's just treating the symptoms and is not a true fix.

You need a socket tutorial. This carnage comes because you are not relying on best practices. Socket reading loops are actually rather simple if done right. This code is a collection of what can go wrong.